# How to get src of an IFrame after i have preformed a Server.Transfer?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an `IFrame` loading multiple pages, after the page submits the `C#` Behind code uses Server.Transfer to move the `IFrames` view to my Success page.

When I check the `src` on the onload event it always shows the `src` path to the original page and not my success page.

This is how I check the `src`:

```
var arr = $('#IFrameDam').attr('src').split('.');
var src = arr[0].toString() + "." + arr[1].toString();
if (src == "GISuccess.aspx" || src == "GIFailed.aspx" || src == "GIConstruction.aspx") {
  //do something
}
```

---

Edit

Using `var action = $('#IFrameDam')[0].contentWindow.location;`

Still does not get me GISuccess.aspx

[image]

Comment: That's the functionality of `Server.Transfer`, try `Response.Redirect`

Comment: @Satpal Ok then what should i use? I tried response.Redirect and had the same problem.

Comment: Response.Redirect("GISuccess.aspx"); Is how i have it in my code. There are no problems it redirects but in the onload of the IFrame i can pick up its src, it still points to the original main page eg. GIITSupportTicket.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` attribute of an `iframe` is a property that exists outside the page displayed in the `iframe`. Navigation inside the `iframe` does not change it. If the `iframe` and the parent page are on the same domain, you can establish javascript communication between them and obtain `iframe.contentWindow.location`.

**Update:**

About `Server.Transfer`. When a browser window is told to obtain content (e.g. html page) from a url, it contacts the server at that url to get the response content. For the browser, html that comes back corresponds to that url. When you use `Server.Transfer`, the html output from the page to which you transfer is the response content, regardless of what the actual (true) url of the latter page is. When `Response.Redirect` is used - it goes back to the browser telling it to obtain the content from the new url specified in `Redirect`.

Comment: @Pomster: @Satpal's point about `Response.Redirect` is still valid.

Comment: @lgor Then what can i use to stop that functionality so i can grab the src?

Comment: Thanks, using IFrame.ContentWindow.Location with Response.Redirect does give the correct page name.